# Displaying a PDF with UIWebView Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

So, I realize that there have been many questions regarding using a UIWebView to display a PDF in an app (on the iPad). I have reviewed everything I can find but I can't seem to find any satisfaction.

What I'm trying to do is very basic so I really don't know why it's not working. All I need to do is display a locally stored PDF in the UIWebView. Essentially, all I'm getting is a black screen. If someone could take a look at my code, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
   - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // Segue to the materials screen.

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"materials"]) {
        PDFViewController *pdfViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        int row = [path row];
        Lesson *selected = [purchasedLessons objectAtIndex:row];
        pdfViewController.selectedLesson = selected ;

    //Start Load PDF in UIWebView

        pdfViewController.pdfWindowTitle.title = selected.titleAndSubtitle;

        pdfViewController.pdfWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 704)];

        NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"moonlightSonataFirstMovement" ofType:@"pdf"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];

        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [pdfViewController.pdfWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

    //End Load PDF

    }
}
```

I've checked to see if my object is bring passed into the scene properly (and it is) and if I am getting a proper request out; i'm getting:

`<NSURLRequest file://localhost/Users/MYCOMPUTER/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/AB161E57-D942-44C2-AA75-030087820BED/iLessons%20Piano.app/moonlightSonataFirstMovement.pdf>`

Also, I've have this error message:

```
iLessons Piano[23080:f803] DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory.
```

Additionally, the NSLog message gets printed out 8 times for some reason.

The only thing I can think of is that I need to do this loading when I call my prepareForSegue function in the previous scene. That or use a different method like Quartz. But I'd rather use a UIWebView since all I really need to do is display and allow scrolling.

Comment: Just a quick thought, is the name correct? Device path is always case sensitive.

Comment: Yea, I wish it was just the filename. I've checked it a few times. It matches :( It's "moonlightSonataFirstMovement.pdf".

Comment: I tried moving the code into the prepareForSegue function but still nothing. Just a black screen.

Comment: I uploaded a zip of my project if anyone wants to take a look at the whole thing to see if they can figure out what's going on. Thanks. http://www.mediafire.com/?6z6q3muw4taufyi

Comment: @Barks actually i didn't involved in the storyBoard and these wired stuff :) but your pdfWebView value is set to nil when you are try to load the request .. find the reason of that.

Comment: @Malek_Jundi So, I figured that my pdfWebView was showing nil because I didn't initialize it. So I tried that and it gave me this error message: "2012-03-07 18:27:07.475 iLessons Piano[26022:f803] DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory.
Mar  7 18:27:08 Brandon-Barkss-MacBook-Pro.local iLessons Piano[26022] <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.
Mar  7 18:27:08 Brandon-Barkss-MacBook-Pro.local iLessons Piano[26022] <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix." Any ideas?

Comment: I also uploaded an other version of the project with the alloc/init put in. http://www.mediafire.com/?co17m2h1ucdsmhp

Comment: @Barks this usually because of the frame of control .. if you check it you will find the frame of the webView is (0,0,0,0) .. also its strange thats your view is black .. please check if you connected everything in the storyBoard as must .. and check the value of your view.

Comment: @Malek_Jundi Well, I changed the init method to initWithFrame and set it to 1024x704 (the size of my pdfWebView). No error message now but I still have a black screen :( I've uploaded another zip with the change I made. http://www.mediafire.com/?qeh2f2md84fvkey As for the connections, I checked the UIWebView in IB and it's connected to the pdfWebView item in the view controller. And I know that the Lesson object is being found properly because it sets the title in the pdfView properly. I'm really confused as to what is going on...

Comment: @Malek_Jundi I did find a missing connection but it didn't fix anything. I forgot to connect by tableView outlet in my ViewController.h to my table view item on the storyboard. I've uploaded a new zip with the change. http://www.mediafire.com/?2w8hfvpxq39w9q9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not sure about whats going on .. you view and webView both holding nil value.. as i told you im not involved in the storyBoard yet .. but you as a workaround solution maybe this fix your problem

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1027, 768)];
    pdfViewController.view = view;
    pdfViewController.pdfWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:pdfViewController.view.frame];

    NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"moonlightSonataFirstMovement" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [pdfViewController.view addSubview:pdfViewController.pdfWebView];
    [pdfViewController.pdfWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! I just dropped it into the prepareForSegue function and voila. It must be that I wasn't creating the frame for the rendering to take place or something. I'll have to tear it apart at some point to figure it out but for not, it's working, and that's fantastic :)

Comment: lol...maybe I spoke too soon. I changed the @"moonlightSonataFirstMovement" string for selected.materialsFilename expecting that it would then be able to load whichever pdf was selected but while it seems that it is selecting the right lesson (whose materialsFilename property is @"") I am still getting the moonlightSonataFirstMovement PDF being loaded...So confused...

Comment: sorry but i didn't get your point .. so now you are try to load another pdf but you always have the moonlightSonataFirstMovement loading ?

Comment: Yea, what I want the app to do is to load whatever PDF is related to the selected Lesson object. So each Lesson object (corresponding to each table cell) will have a "materialsFilename" property which is simply a string that holds the filename. Currently, I have it set to blank for Lesson2 and Lesson3 whereas I have it set to @"moonlightSonataFirstMovement" for Lesson1. When the user selects a lesson from the tableView and then taps the "Materials" button, they should be taken to the PDF viewer screen and the proper PDF should be shown.

Comment: aha i see .. you are getting the same pdf because the (int row) is always return 0 and thats because the indexPath is nil and thats because you are not connecting your tableView IBOutlet :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I fixed that problem :( I put in a breakpoint and it seems that the row int is being set properly...Here's the project with the tableView all connected properly http://www.mediafire.com/?d49hladfsdawufr

Comment: ok i cant see any problem right now ! put another pdf on your project and assign the second lesson materialsFilename to the name of pdf and you will got it loaded on the webview .

Comment: lol...I can't believe I didn't try it with a test PDF. I just figured that if I left it blank it should just show a blank screen. Well, I added one and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much Malek_Jundi. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

> DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old
>   directory.

This one isn't the real reason the app crashes. This warning can be fixed by assigning the view in the Storyboard. It seems like it's connected already but it's grey. So assign it again and it will be fine.

The real issue for me was that the PDF images were 300 DPI and it took too long to load the application. Since the debugger keeps the app from crashing it seems to work fine but the loading will take too long without the debugger and will result in a timeout crash.

There's a few things you can do. You can downscale your PDF which might be a good thing anyway since older device are even slower and it's nice to support those as well. But what really fixes it is by delaying the PageView initialization. Here's what I did:

In the RootViewController I moved the code from the `viewDidLoad` to a new function `setupPageViewer`.

And put this in the `viewDidLoad`:

> [self performSelector:@selector(setupPageViewer) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];

The delay 0.0 means it will be taken care of in the next frame which gives you the opportunity to show a loading indicator.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can disable or remove your 'All Exceptions' breakpoint. This might make debugging a little more difficult, but it's not as bad as having to relaunch the application all the time.

[image]

This is the breakpoint causing the issue. I had set it so long ago that I'd forgotten it was there