# iOS: Exception when poping a UIViewController with a UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, uiwebview, automatic-ref-counting

I have a small iOS app with a storyboard. The initial view controller is a UINavigationController with a RootViewController, which has a UIButton. I have a segue from the button to another view controller with a UIWebView. I test with automatic breakpoints for thrown exceptions and when I push the WebViewController, wait until a pdf is loaded and then push the "back" button to pop the view controller I get an exception without any console output. This app uses ARC. I am using Xcode 4.4.1 and in Xcode 4.5 I don't get an exception.

```
ViewController.m
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pdf"]){
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tonyromas.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Tonyromas_Drinks.pdf"]];
        [(WebViewController*)segue.destinationViewController setRequest:request];
    }
}
WebViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.wView loadRequest:self.request];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:
0xeb2caa:  pushl  %ebp
0xeb2cab:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0xeb2cad:  pushl  %ebx
0xeb2cae:  pushl  %edi
0xeb2caf:  pushl  %esi
0xeb2cb0:  subl   $2028, %esp
0xeb2cb6:  calll  0xeb2cbb                  ; objc_exception_throw + 17
0xeb2cbb:  popl   %edi
0xeb2cbc:  movl   $16, (%esp)
0xeb2cc3:  calll  0xec7830                  ; symbol stub for: __cxa_allocate_exception
```

Answer (score 0):

this includes a workaround.. but I believe their original code is still correct (just at a glance).

[Displaying a PDF with UIWebView Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606646/displaying-a-pdf-with-uiwebview-not-working)

Comment: I will have a look on that soon. Thank you.